# How does DES provide confusion and diffusion?

Tags: encryption, des

I know that Data Encryption Standard (DES) provide strong security but I want to know how does it provides confusion and diffusion?

Comment: DES and strong security in one sentence, funny.

Answer (score 5):

Confusion and diffusion aren't *attributes* provided by DES, but rather the building blocks of creating a cipher like DES. In the case of DES, the confusion step is the S-box substitution, while the diffusion step is where the output of the S-boxes is rearranged according to the P-box permutation rules.

See [Wikipedia: DES](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Encryption_Standard) for the actual details.